# Specifics, books or open source projects about p2p algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, open-source, p2p

I am planning to build a p2p micro-blog community without a central server, looking for learning materials about p2p algorithms; open sources projects will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitTorrent is in fact open source. There's also the Tribler project which is very actively being developed, it's an extension to BitTorrent without the need for central servers providing torrent files.

Comment: [Tribler](http://www.tribler.org/trac) is what i am looking for, thank you, @Nicolas78